# How To Read Multiple Integers from a String C++

Tags: c++, string, integer, atoi, istringstream

I'm trying to understand how can I convert multiple integers from a string. I have tried to use `atoi()`, `stoi()` and `istringstream()` and they all do the same thing. I can't get more than one integer.

For example, if the string is `"Chocolate and Milk 250 pounds and 2 oz or 1.5 coins."`
All of the above functions will not work. It won't take the whole string. If I leave only a single number then it will work. I want to be able to read the whole string and get all of the *integers only* (not *float*).

I am using a `while(getline())` for the string. Then try to get it into string.

Although, if I could only return the total amount of integers in the string that would be better. Either way, I'm trying to learn both ways. In this case, the output would be `"2"`, since there are only two int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to split the string using  as delimiter and using `stoi` on individual strings to check if they are integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string s = "Chocolate and Milk 250 pounds and 2 oz or 1.5 coins.";
    int count = 0;
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    std::string token;
    while(getline(iss,token,' ')){
        if(std::isdigit(token[0]) &&stoi(token) && token.find('.')==std::string::npos){
            count++;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<count<<std::endl;
}
```

Note that more complex checks can be done on strings if `stoi` succeeds, but the input is not a valid integer. You can have a helper function which checks if all the characters are digits or not by using `isdigit` etc.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with "try", "catch". That's beyond my skills. I'm still learning some basics, specially loops. Is there an easier way then to do all of that? Perhaps only a way to return the amount of integers in the string than to read and convert the string to int (not float)?

Comment: You can also simply include `<cctype>` and check `isdigit(token[0])` and if so, then convert with `stof` and check whether then the fractional part is greater than some small number like `1E-5` and if so, leave it as a float, if not reinterpret as an integer value. All `try {...} catch {...}` does is try the conversion, if it fails an exception is thrown that will be caught by the `catch` part -- allowing you to handle the error (in this case, just skip to the next token) See [try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

Comment: `try/catch` is easy to understand. However, I'll edit the answer to not use it and apply something similar to above comment.

Comment: It may also be worth explaining that `token.find('.')==std::string::npos` checks for the presence of a `'.'` in the `token` to discard the conversion of `1.5` and to also make clear that the conversion to `int` of `"1.5"` would convert the value to `1` stopping conversion when the `'.'` was reached. Good job.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I appreciate it a lot. Could you please explain to me what is `npos`, like what does it do. Based on the `if()` function, is there a possible way to make it simpler? I'm just saying that because there are some things in that function that I'm not familiar like I said before. I've never used an `if()` statement that is that large with a lot of arguments before.

Comment: I understand token.find('.'), but not `npos`. Thank you anyways for that, it means a lot.

Comment: `token.find('.')==std::string::npos)` this is checking if there is a decimal point in the string. If it's found, find returns the position in the string where the dot is. If it's not found, then it returns `npos` which is equivalent to -1.

Comment: The if condition is combining three conditions. token[0] to be a digit, then stoi(token) to convert to an integer and the last condition token.find to check if there is no decimal point. All these should be true for the token to be integer